# Creating X509 Certificate in Java with TBSCertificate

Tags: java, cryptography, certificate, bouncycastle, x509

I have the following given function:

```
public TBSCertificate gerarEstruturaCertificado(PublicKey chavePublica,
                                                    int numeroDeSerie, String nome,
                                                    String nomeAc, int dias) {
        // TODO implementar
        return null;
}
```

And I need to generate a TBSCertificate object with the given arguments, but I can't seem to find any way to do it. The closest I got was when I found this: https://www.mayrhofer.eu.org/post/create-x509-certs-in-java/ , but I can't make the following line work:

```
DERObjectIdentifier sigOID = X509Util.getAlgorithmOID(“SHA1WithRSAEncryption”);
```

because I can't seem to import the X509Util from anywhere.

Here are some imports that I should use:

```
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1EncodableVector;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.DERBitString;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.AlgorithmIdentifier;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.TBSCertificate;
import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.X509CertificateObject;

import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.PublicKey;
```

Any advice?

Comment: [org.bouncycastle.x509.X509Util](https://github.com/bcgit/bc-java/blob/master/prov/src/main/java/org/bouncycastle/x509/X509Util.java). But using SHA1 signature for a cert is a bad idea; NIST prohibited it for US govt as of 2014, CABforum prohibited it for the public web as of 2015, and it was actually [broken for collision in 2017](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/44131/what-is-shattered-and-how-does-it-work) so more and more systems are moving to distrust it. And using a 'serial' number that is actually serial or fits in Java `int` can also be dangerous, but is not yet prohibited.